# Creating a hyperlink using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a hyperlink using the following code

```
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
cell.setCellValue("Click Here");
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);

File f = new File("C:\\Test\\1.pdf");
link.setAddress(f.getCanonicalPath());
cell.setHyperlink((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink) link);
```

It works fine and it adds a link ***`Click Here`*** to the cell

But how i can set a partial text and a link using same type of code, 
 I mean the link need to be like ***`your file is`*** *`here`*, where only here is the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know I don't think it is possible, as it is not supported by `Excel` as well. To achieve that in `Excel` too there is no straight way and you have to do some tricks to achieve that. Something that is not supported right from `Excel` cannot be supported by `Apache POI` too.